# Ignore specific http status codes from errors

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a web application monitored with Application Insights but in the errors view I see non 500 http status responses being registered as errors. Is there a way to tell insights to only register 500 status codes or ignore 400 status codes from the captured events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. What you can do is [register a custom Telemetry Initializer](http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/01/telemetry-initializers/) and do something like this:

```
 public void Initialize(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Channel.ITelemetry telemetry)
 {
            if (telemetry is RequestTelemetry && ((RequestTelemetry)telemetry).ResponseCode == "400")
            {
               ((RequestTelemetry)telemetry).Success = true;
            }
 }
```